# Record audio from microphone into .wav format and playback using AudioUnit in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to record audio data from microphone in `.wav` file and playback it. I need also actual data (amplitude) for ploting graph so i am using `AudioUnit`. I setup inputCallBack and renderCallBack for `AudioUnit` object But i don't know how to write AudioBuffers to `.wav` file from `render_CallBack` mehtod. I attached my code what i have tried till now.

Please help me...

Step - 1

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioStreamBasicDesc;
AudioUnit.AudioUnit audioUnit;
string m_recordingFilePath;
ExtAudioFile extAudioFileObj;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();        

    audioStreamBasicDesc.SampleRate = 16000;
    audioStreamBasicDesc.Format = AudioFormatType.LinearPCM;
    audioStreamBasicDesc.FramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioStreamBasicDesc.ChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    audioStreamBasicDesc.BytesPerFrame = 
                                audioStreamBasicDesc.ChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(short);
    audioStreamBasicDesc.BytesPerPacket = 
                                audioStreamBasicDesc.ChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(short);
    audioStreamBasicDesc.BitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioStreamBasicDesc.Reserved = 0;
    audioStreamBasicDesc.FormatFlags = AudioFormatFlags.IsSignedInteger | 
                                       AudioFormatFlags.IsPacked;

    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var tmp = Path.Combine(documents, "..", "tmp");
    m_recordingFilePath = Path.Combine(tmp, 
        String.Format("{0}.wav", 
            "MyFile" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss",
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));       
    extAudioFileObj = ExtAudioFile.CreateWithUrl(CFUrl.FromFile(m_recordingFilePath), 
                                                 AudioFileType.WAVE, 
                                                 audioStreamBasicDesc, 
                                                 AudioFileFlags.EraseFlags);
    prepareAudioUnit();
}
```

Step - 2

```
public void prepareAudioUnit()
{                            
    var _audioComponent =   AudioComponent.FindComponent(AudioTypeOutput.Remote);

    audioUnit = _audioComponent.CreateAudioUnit();

    audioUnit = new AudioUnit.AudioUnit(_audioComponent);

    audioUnit.SetEnableIO(true,
        AudioUnitScopeType.Input,
        1 // Remote Input
    );

    // setting audio format
    audioUnit.SetAudioFormat(audioStreamBasicDesc,
        AudioUnitScopeType.Output,
        1
    );                                    

    audioUnit.SetInputCallback(input_CallBack, AudioUnitScopeType.Input, 1);

    audioUnit.SetRenderCallback(render_CallBack, AudioUnitScopeType.Global, 0);          

    audioUnit.Initialize();
    audioUnit.Start();
}
```

Step - 3

```
AudioUnitStatus input_CallBack(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags actionFlags, 
                               AudioTimeStamp timeStamp, 
                               uint busNumber,
                               uint numberFrames, 
                               AudioUnit.AudioUnit audioUnit)
{
    return AudioUnitStatus.NoError;
}
```

Step - 4

```
AudioUnitStatus render_CallBack(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags actionFlags, 
                                AudioTimeStamp timeStamp, 
                                uint busNumber, 
                                uint numberFrames, 
                                AudioBuffers data)
{
    // getting microphone input signal
    var status = audioUnit.Render(ref actionFlags,
                                 timeStamp,
                                 1, // Remote input
                                 numberFrames,
                                 data);
    if (status != AudioUnitStatus.OK)
    {
        return status;
    }

    //get pointer to buffer
    var outP = data[0].Data;
    unsafe
    {
        var outPtr = (int*)outP.ToPointer();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberFrames; i++)
        {
            var val = *outPtr;
            outPtr++;
            //lastestPickVal = val; //This is for ploting graph
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
    extAudioFileObj.ClientDataFormat = audioStreamBasicDesc;
    //Here i am trying to write data into .wav file and file is generated also 
    //but corrupted file without actual data (create file size is approx 4kb or 100 kb )
    var err = extAudioFileObj.Write(numberFrames, data); 
    Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT" + busNumber);
    return AudioUnitStatus.NoError;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote an IAudioStream abstraction for Xamarin and it might be of little help to you. It gets the byte buffer from AudioQueueBuffer and what you might be looking for is marshalling the buffer to bytes:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.iOS/Services/Media/Microphone.cs#L125-L132

There is also a WAV recorder class that hooks into the source and writes it to WAV but that's after the raw signal has been extracted:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform/Services/Media/WaveRecorder.cs

I hope these will give you at least some help going forward.